# Data reconciliation in Hadoop in the most primitive way

Tags: java, hadoop, hashmap, mapreduce, hdfs

I need to do data reconciliation in Hadoop based on key comparisons. That means I will have old data in one folder and the newer data will be put into different folders. At the end of the batch I was planning simply on moving the newer data to reside with the old one. The data would be json files from which I have to extract the keys.

I'm taking my first steps with Hadoop so I just wanna do it with MapReduce program only, i.e. **without** tools such as Spark, Pig, Hive etc. I was thinking of simply going through all the old data at the beginning of the program, before Job object creation, and putting all the IDs into a Java HashMap that would be accessible from the mapper task. If there's a key missing in the newer data, the mapper would output that. The reducer would concern itself with categories of the IDs that are missing but that's another story. After the job has finished, I would move the newer data into old data's folder.

The only thing that I find a bit clunky is this loading phase into Java HashMap object. This is not probably the most elegant solution so I was wondering if MapReduce model has some dedicated data structures/functionality for that kind of purpose (**populating a global hash map with all the data from HDFS before the first map task is run**)?

Comment: I get your point but I'd still just use Spark.

Comment: @BenWatson I totally understand, but if I were to do it in MapReduce, then this unsightly HashMap is my only option?

Comment: Hashmap is not a distributed data structure. It won't work in mapreduce unless you only want one mapper or reducer (which defeats the purpose of MR)

Comment: Trying to dedupe/count keys? Use HBase or Accumulo or just Redis

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm trying to check which previous keys are not present in the current batch. I need to use MapReduce because it's a school project ^^ I guess I will just load all of the keys in each instance of Mapper arguing that the volume of new keys is much larger than the old ones, so that this loading phase will be dwarfed by new data processing...

Comment: You can still use each of the mentioned tools with MapReduce. E.g https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/_chapters/mapreduce.adoc

Answer (score 0):

I think solution with HashMap is not a good idea. You can use few inputs for your command.
Depends on input file mapper can understand if this data is new and write it with suitable value. Then reducer will check if this data is contained only in "new input" and write this data.
So as result of job you will get only new data.